# Execute code before application end

Tags: vb.net, winforms, mdi, formclosing

I got MDI application and have some OnFormClosing event which is doing some job before End app - those lines:

```
Projekt.UnlockAllLockedProjects()
End 'completly close app
```

And below entire code:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnFormClosing(e As FormClosingEventArgs)
    MyBase.OnFormClosing(e)

    If e.CloseReason = CloseReason.WindowsShutDown Then
        Return
    End If

    Dim dr As DialogResult
    Select Case Lang.name
        Case Lang.LangShortcut.PL
            dr = MessageBox.Show(Me, "Kontynuować zamykanie okna?", MsgLevel.QUESTION.ToString, MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
        Case Lang.LangShortcut.EN
            dr = MessageBox.Show(Me, "Are you sure you want to quit?", MsgLevel.ZAPYTANIE.ToString, MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
        Case Else
    End Select

    ' Confirm user wants to close
    Select Case dr
        Case DialogResult.No
            e.Cancel = True
            Exit Select
        Case Else
              Projekt.UnlockAllLockedProjects()
            End 'completly close app
    End Select
End Sub
```

The question is, let's assume there will be application error therefore application will crash or manually I put somewhere else in code `End` clause. How can I make sure `Projekt.UnlockAllLockedProjects()` will be always executed before app exit. Is there any place to put it and be sure of that?

Comment: What is the entry point of program? Is it MDI form, `Sub Main` or any other form. And also is this MDI form always the last form of the application i.e. are there multiple MDI forms or any other non-MDI child that may be active even after this MDI is closed?

Comment: the first form is Login form when user typing credentials if they are correct i am showing new form which is mdi container and hiding Login form

Comment: Never use `End`. There is no reason to do anything to end the app there because it will end *unless* you cancel.  That should usually work if that form is the last form to close (and thats how you apparently have the app configured) and there is not some unhandled exception elsewhere

Comment: ok but is there any chance/any place in case of unplanned error occur which i could place my code to be sure it will be executed before?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a Sub Main in a module that will display the GUI and ultimately handle the unlocking process in a Try...Catch.

1. Add a module to the project.
2. Add a Sub Main to the module.
3. In Sub Main, use a Try...Catch to display a form and handle exceptions.
4. Set the Startup object to Sub Main (Project>Properties>Application).

Example:

```
Module Program

    Public Sub Main(ByVal cmdArgs() As String)
        Try
            Application.Run(frmLogin)
        Catch ex As Exception
            'Any special code for handling exceptions goes here.
        Finally
            Projekt.UnlockAllLockedProjects()
        End Try
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: I should add that this code won't work if you use an End statement. That ends execution immediately. This should handle most any exception however whether they are explicitly raised or are the result of some inadvertent runtime condition.